# Avoid Cassandra full table scan cross DC

Tags: cassandra, datastax, cassandra-3.0

I have Cassandra cluster nodes distributed across 2 data centers. 6 nodes in each data center, a total of 12 nodes

My keyspace definition:

```
CREATE KEYSPACE my_keyspace WITH replication = {'class': 'NetworkTopologyStrategy', 'dc1': '3', 'dc2': '3'} AND durable_writes = true;
```

In each node, I have 64 tokens.

I am using Cassandra driver to connect to the cluster and using default load balancing policy DCAwareRoundRobinPolicy and using only `dc1` nodes as contact points. So, I assume `dc2` nodes will have `HostDistance` `IGNORED` and my application won't connect to them.

Note: For all my reads and writes I use the same configuration

My use case is to do a full table scan. But, I can not use Spark. So, instead, I an achieving this by getting all token range using `metadata.getTokenRanges()` and querying these token ranges in multiple threads.

Everything works fine. But, `metadata.getTokenRanges()` return 768 tokens(64*12). Which means it's giving me token range across all 12 nodes.

Since I have to run through all token ranges. Even with multiple threads, the process is very slow.
Is there any way I can get token ranges of only one data center. I even tried to get token ranges using `metadata.getTokenRanges("my_keyspace", host from dc1)`. 
I do get less number of tokens(517), but when I use this list, I get fewer data.

How can I get token ranges of only 1 DC?

Edit: I checked read/write latency in both the clusters. I do not see any operations being performed on `dc2`, whereas I can see a clear spike on my `dc1` data center.

This is even more puzzling for me now. If `dc2` is never queried how I am getting `64*12 +1` token ranges? and why not `64*6+1`?

Comment: At which Consistency level are you firing query? In case of Local-*, it is obvious to see spike on one dc.

Comment: Default LOCAL_ONE

Answer (score 0):

Your `replication_factor` is `3+3=6`. So you may have 6 times the actual data. 3 copies in dc1 and 3 copies in dc2.

You have 64 vnodes per node so `64*12 =768` vnodes.

So, if you want to do a complete table scan then you might have to query all the token ranges i.e 768. What you are missing is that, because of the replication all that token ranges' data will reside within dc1. So you can get all the data from dc1 itself.

If you are using `DCAwareRoundRobinPolicy` and set `.withLocalDc()` with dc1 and consistency level `LOCAL_*` then you are reading only from dc1. dc1 will have all the data because the `replication_factor` of dc1 is 3.